# Custom Tally Counter

Tags: iphone, counter, picker

I'm developing on a tally counter app. It should have a custom picker view like display showing the current count. Something like the one found in the simple, but nice, app from [Pixel Research Labs](http://pixelresearchlabs.com/tallycounter).

I've started to read a book on Core Animations, since I think this is the place to find what I'm looking for. Am I right? Does anybody know a tutorial or some other resource that could help my develop this custom picker?

Oh, just to clear it up: I don't wanna make use of the picker view from the iPhone SDK. I can't customize it enough for my needs.

Looking forward to hear from you. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the effect they are using is the "liner bump distortion". I would recommend looking at the Core Image Funhouse and playing around to find what produces the effect you want. Then you can see what is available to do that on the iPhone.

You also remember that you can highly customize the look of the UIPickerView by using custom row views. I pretty certain I could create a picker view that looks like the one from Pixel Research Labs.

---

### Edit01:

You might look at "Core Animation for Mac OS X" and the iPhone by Bill Dudely. I've just leafed through it so I don't know if it has the answer you need or not. I would like to know exactly how to do this as well.

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer.

I played around with Core Image Fun House, and I see your idea with the bump distortion. Though I'm having problems finding out if the iPhone supports it. Doesn't look like it.

I can customize the images for the picker view, yes. But not the height of the view. It has some fixed dimensions. I would love to see, if you could get a result like Total Counter using a picker view. I'm having a hard time seeing how it should work.

Comment: You're right that you can't change the dimensions of the UIPickerView's bounds.